# Looking for an alternative to this broken stay for a drop leaf

Tags: hinges

I'm having trouble trying to source a replacement for the stay pictured below

[image]
https://photos.app.goo.gl/wQSDOYk8U0kD0ptx2

Can anyone suggest an alternative that might be more readily available (ideally in the UK)

The shaped part sits in a recess on the side of the cabinet and allow the leaf to drop down, move forward and be held. Not the best explanation but hopefully clear enough.

Answer (score 1):

A fellow was referred to our makerspace with a similar problem, slightly more complex than yours. The solution was to have a member purchase raw brass stock (expensive) and mill the shape necessary to create the desired part.

As in your case, the expense was secondary to the lack of availability of a retail part.

You may be able to locate a makerspace in your area with members of sufficient skill and equipment to duplicate this process.

Your part is not particularly complex and may be possible to create with hand tools. This consideration does not exclude it from the local makerspace concept.